# Font Awesome icon in input placeholder not working

Tags: html

I am trying to use Font Awesome icons in the input placeholder.

I tried this but not working.

```
<body>
   <input type="text" placeholder="&#xF002;" style="font-family:FontAwesome"/>
</body>
```

What’s wrong with this? I am getting some weird number in the placeholder instead of icon.

Comment: I tested the code on font-awesome website and it works fine, can you please confirm if the font is being picked by the input field or it is overridden by some other CSS. It will be better if you could produce a fiddle.

Comment: Instead of using directly font:fontawesome add ariel type also

Answer (score 10):

You can add font awesome icon as like that

```
<input type="text" placeholder="&#xF002" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" />
```

you can also check out the fiddle [Fiddle click here](https://jsfiddle.net/7fzf83ev/)

Comment: You can also use pseudo class

Comment: Chk yur fontawesome file is included or not? Chk view source @nag

Comment: i've added this in the <head> tag, <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

Comment: Open this url in yur browser chk working or not @nag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100823/discussion-between-devpro-and-nag).

Comment: I open it but gives me error... well chk console is file included properly @nag

Comment: This lead me to right direction. With Angular Material I needed add FontAwesome to my typography declaration.
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: '"Open Sans", "FontAwesome"') like this

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an icon outside of placeholder, placed with HTML. Here is my solution:

```
HTML
<i class="fas fa-search form__icon"></i>
<input type="text" name="search" class="form__input" placeholder="      Search">
```

```
CSS
.form__icon {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}
.form__input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.form__input:placeholder-shown {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

It's a bit complex, but it also give a possibility to use animated, rotated and flipped icons.

Check my CodePen: https://codepen.io/dzakh/pen/YzKqJvy

Answer (score 1):

When you try to use a font icon and what you get is some weird character, this is probably due to the fact that the browser tries to render that icon with a wrong font. Check what your `input`'s `font-family` is when rendered by inspecting the element, and then going into the 'Computed' tab (Chrome: Right click -> Inspect Element -> Computed). If it's not font-awesome, but you think you set it, try to use `font-family: FontAwesome !important;`. This will override any of the possible input's parrent `font-family` setting.